# Is there a way to search for pattern across cells?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

For example I have a row (row 1) like:

0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1

In script, can I specify something like ('1', '0', 0') and have the correct range (here C1:E1) return to me?

Comment: I want to do it with script and write some custom function for checking work scheduling

Comment: You could add more details. Do you want to write the pattern somewhere into the spreadsheet? Also, in which form do you want the result to be? A1 notation? And what exactly do you need this for?

Comment: what you ask is only possible by writting apps script code. see spreadsheetApp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need something like this:

```
function findPattern() {
  var aSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Form Responses 2");
  var pattern = "100",
      howManyRows = 0,
      howManyColums = 0,
      i=0,
      valuesAsString="",
      startCol=0;

  howManyRows = aSheet.getLastRow();
  howManyColums =  aSheet.getLastColumn();

  for (i=0;i<howManyRows;i+=1) { //Go through every row in the sheet
    var range = aSheet.getRange(i+1, 1, 1, howManyColums);
    valuesAsString = range.getValues().join();
    valuesAsString = valuesAsString.replace(/,/g,"");
    //Logger.log("valuesAsString: " + valuesAsString);
    startCol = valuesAsString.indexOf(pattern);
    Logger.log('startCol: ' + startCol);

    if (startCol!==-1) {
      Logger.log('Pattern found in row: ' + (i + 1) + ' Pattern starts in column: ' + (startCol + 1))
    };
  };
};
```

Comment: Thank you, with you sample I worked out the problem. Originally I think perhaps there is an add-on somewhere that I can readily use, but your solution is simple enough, thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.